# How to write/print text to the console (stdout) in Java

Tags: java

I want to print something to the console, similar to `console.log` in JavaScript, `puts` in Ruby, `println` in Kotlin, etc.

But Java doesn't have top-level functions or any obvious console-related classes in the standard library.  What class or method do I use to simply write text to the console (stdout)?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to print text to the console with a newline at the end, you can use [**`System.out.println`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html), like so:

```java
System.out.println("text here");
```

This will output:

```
text here
```

If you are familiar with C, this is equivalent to `puts("text here");`.

---

If you want to print text *without* a newline character at the end, you can use **`System.out.print`**:

```java
System.out.print("Hello, ");
System.out.println("world!");
```

This will output:

```
Hello, world!
```

Note that the two strings appear on the same line, despite being printed separately.

If you are familiar with C, this is equivalent to `fputs("text here", stdout);` and/or `printf("text here");`

---

You can also substitute `System.out` with `System.err` in either of the above two commands to write to stderr instead of stdout. In the typical case, both streams will appear in the console, but they can be separately redirected using the appropriate OS-specific commands when running your Java application.